# How to get system config values in controller ? Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get system values
using this but not getting the expected values

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('web/cookie/cookie_httponly');
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

> $configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/cookie/cookie_httponly',
> Mage::app()->getStore());